# Create a pull request from an imported repository to the parent repository

Tags: git, github, repository

I have two repositories: X and Y.
Y is created by the "Import" option on GitHub since you cannot fork your own repository in the same account (or same organization) on GitHub.

I have made some changes on repo Y and pushed them into remote repo Y. Now, I want to make a pull request from repo Y onto repo X, but on GitHub, I don't see any option to do that. Is there any way to do this?

If there is no other option, I would also like to know if there is any way by which I can create a remote clone of the same repository (repo X in this case) under the same account/organization after which I can create a pull request from repo Y to repo X.